# Why expm(2*A) != expm(A) @ expm(A)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

According to the rule `exp(A+B) = exp(A)exp(B)`, which holds for commuting matrices `A` and `B`, i.e. when `AB = BA`, we have that `exp(2A) = exp(A)exp(A)`. However when I run the following in Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm

A = np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4)

print(expm(2*A))
[[ 306.63168024  344.81465009  380.01335176  432.47730444]
 [ 172.59336774  195.36562731  214.19453937  243.76985501]
 [ -35.40485583  -39.87705598  -42.94545895  -50.01324379]
 [-168.44316833 -190.32607875 -209.76427134 -237.72069322]]

print(expm(A) @ expm(A))
[[1.87271814e+30 2.12068332e+30 2.36864850e+30 2.61661368e+30]
 [4.32685652e+30 4.89977229e+30 5.47268806e+30 6.04560383e+30]
 [6.78099490e+30 7.67886126e+30 8.57672762e+30 9.47459398e+30]
 [9.23513328e+30 1.04579502e+31 1.16807672e+31 1.29035841e+31]]
```

I get two very different results. Note that `@` is just the matrix product.

I also tried it in Matlab and the two results are the same as expected. What am I missing here?

**Edit**: I have NumPy 1.15.3, SciPy 1.1.0, Python 3.6.4, Windows 7 64-bit

As suggested in comments by [Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser), using `A = A.astype(np.float64)` solves the problem.

Comment: Maybe this is related to the rounding errors?

Comment: What version of `numpy`? on `'1.15.0'`, `(expm(2*A) == expm(A)@expm(A)).all()` returns `TRUE`

Comment: I have Numpy '1.15.3'

Comment: Which version of `scipy`?  (You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.)

Comment: My guess is you are using Windows.  `A` is an integer array, and on Windows, the default integer type is 32 bits.  As pointed out by @sophros in an answer, there is a bug in `scipy.linalg.expm` that is apparently the result of integer overflow of an intermediate calculation.  Try converting `A` to floating point or 64 bit integers first, e.g. `A = np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4).astype(np.float64)`.

Comment: FYI: I can reproduce your results by using `A = np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4).astype(np.int32)`.

Comment: One more note: I reproduced the problem using `A = np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4).astype(np.int32)` in SciPy 1.1.0.  I also have the development version installed (version `'1.2.0.dev0+dfc9a9c'`), and the problem does *not* occur there.  So it looks like the next release will have fixed this.

Comment: I could reproduce the bug on numpy version `1.14.0` with 32 bit integers. The following definitions of A yielded ok: 

    `A = np.arange(1,17, dtype='int64').reshape(4,4)` , 
    `A = np.arange(1,17, dtype='float32').reshape(4,4) `

I'm guessing it has to do with hwo scipy handles the pade approximation for the different bit size, probably an overflow error.

Comment: Is anyone willing to write a short answer so that I can accept it? E.g. Warren Weckesser comments seem enough. Thanks!

Comment: Just for info expm(A + B) != expm(A)expm(B) unless they are commuting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief: there's a bug in scipy 1.1.0 which seems to have been fixed in 1.2.0.

Installing the latest scipy (1.2.1), the following passes just fine:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm

A = np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4)

assert (expm(A) @ expm(A) == expm(2 * A)).all()
```